# Please help to solve my trial exam question thanks!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question goes like this:

> Given that
>   $$(m^2/3)(3/y^3)^m(y/2)^{m+2}=n/y^2,$$
>   Find $m$ and $n$.

the answer is 
$$m=2 ,\quad  n=3/4.$$

I try to assume that y=1, and surprisingly I am able to get the answer. 
However, I am not convinced with this solution as I can put other values for y too.

So how to approach and solve this problem? Please help me as I am going to sit for my final exam. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the question says that the equation is true **for all** non-zero $y$ since otherwise there are lots of solutions.

Simplifying the equation gives:-
$$\frac{m^23^{m-1}}{n2^{m+2}}=y^{2m-4}.$$

For this to hold for all non-zero $y$ we require $2m-4=0$ i.e. $m=2$. We then have 
$$\frac{12}{16n}=1$$ and so $n=\frac{3}{4}.$

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed $m$ and $n$ to be numbers.
$$(m^2/3)(3/y^3)^m(y/2)^{m+2}=n/y^2$$
$$\frac{m^2}{3}*\frac{3^m}{y^{3m}}*\frac{y^{m+2}}{2^{m+2}}=n/y^2$$
$$\frac{m^2}{12}*\frac{3^m}{2^m}*y^{2-2m}=n*y^{-2}$$
**Equating power of $y$**
$$2-2m=-2;m=2$$
And
$$\frac{m^2}{12}*\frac{3^m}{2^m}=n$$
On solving,
$$n=\frac34$$

Comment: how can the power of y be equated? I couldn't get it.

Comment: Assuming $m$ and $n$ are numbers, the coefficient and power of $y$ should be equal.